# Developing in Visual Studio 2010 with the new IIS Express web server?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5, webmatrix

*Although this question isn't directly about code it's related to programming and seems better put here than, say, serverfault or superuser.*

--
I'm a developer with Visual Studio 2010.  Microsoft's newest web server offering for developers is IIS Express. [ScottGu indicated this combination is workable](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx):

> IIS Express will work with VS 2010 and
>   Visual Web Developer 2010 Express,
>   will run on Windows XP and higher
>   systems,

The only option I've seen so far, is to download [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) which contains and uses IIS Express, but I cannot get it hooked into VS 2010, or to download IIS Express separately.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Current of July 11, 2011**

[Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509) includes the option to use [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038) from inside VS2010. 
[Blog post.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288080.aspx)

Or use the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).

Comment: Please feel free to contribute to this answer if you have more info or links. Thanks.

Comment: VS2010 SP1 is now available and includes the option to use IIS Express from inside VS2010

Answer (score 3):

I don't think IIS Express is available for Visual Studio 2010 yet.

Edit: Found it in Scott's post. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx

> We’ll be releasing the first public beta of IIS Express shortly. With the beta you’ll be able to right-click on a file-system folder and have IIS Express launch a web-site based on that file-system location. We’ll also be releasing a patch for VS 2010 and Visual Web Developer 2010 Express later this year that will enable you to automatically launch and use IIS Express in place of VS’s built-in ASP.NET Developer Server.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.intrepidstudios.com/blog/2010/7/11/debug-your-net-web-project-with-iis-express-t.aspx has instructions on using IIS Express with VS2010 if you don't feel like waiting for VS2010 SP1 to be released.

Answer (score 2):

The link to the Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (not beta any longer) is http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5.

Answer (score 1):

Jesper Palm is not correct, I am able to run IIS Express Using Visual Studio after a lot of investigation. What Jaseper is mentioning(ScootGu's blog), I already have read that. Scott is only telling that the patch will be released to run 'IIS Express' within VS2010 IDE but with 'MS Web Matrix Beta 2' It is possible to run IIS EXpress with VS 2010. If u face problem contact me in by e-mail:ankitvbdotnet@yahoo.com

Comment: We have to remember that support for IIS Express will increase over time until it's soon taken for granted that we can use it. This also means, gradually, some relevant answers here will become historic and irrelevant. It's just one of those kinds of questions. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The current [IIS Express Overview](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/) says that VS2008 and VS2010 integration is going to come in a later release (presumably before the RTM release).

> A future update to Visual Studio 2010 will add support for IIS Express. You can also manually configure Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 to use IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that can't/doesn't want to install the SP1 beta then [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jaredroberts/archive/2011/02/09/using-iis-express-with-visual-studio-2010-without-installing-service-pack-1-beta.aspx) will show you how you can incorporate it into your debugging in a relatively easy way.