# Block development server window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, webdev.webserver

Is there any way to avoid the window of development server? (Not stopping or avoiding to run the development server, just the window).

In Visual Studio 2010 (and before) it only appears when the development server was started. Now, in Visual Studio 2012 it is opened each time the project start, no matter if the development server has already started and you have closed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that I can run projects using IIS Express. Also it will make our lives easier when we want to be able to access to the project running from other PC.

With Visual Studio 2012 it comes already installed (in fact is the default setting for projects started in it). With Visual Studio 2010 it can be installed ([see post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355138/developing-in-visual-studio-2010-with-the-new-iis-express-web-server)).