# Fail to reach WCF Data Service over LAN

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I created an ASP.NET WEB project in VS2012 and add a WCF Data Service file(.svc).When i run, i can reach it(localhost:61388/default.svc), but i can't reach it in another computer by typing my host's ip address(192.168.1.4:61388/default.svc) and it shows BAD REQUEST-INVALID HOST NAME.
Then how can I reach my wcf data service from another computer?
I've turned off all firewalls and my os is windows 7 Pro

Comment: 192.168.1.4:61388/default.svc, also make sure you don't have a firewall running. You can't do this with the cassini built in web server, you need to use iis or iis express.

Comment: the port was right and i've turned off firewall, how to use iis or iis express?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355138/developing-in-visual-studio-2010-with-the-new-iis-express-web-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to host your WCF service in IIS server...To learn more about IIS server and add website see [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7)

BY default there is a default website running at port 80.(You can check by typing **http:\localhost**) If you dont get anything that means IIS is not installed in your PC.

Once your IIS is up and running add your WCF service to IIS just like you add website to IIS (Or directly publish your WCF service in IIS publish-->IIS) and give it a specific port number (lets say your WCF service is running at 81).you can access the service from other computer (Lets say the PC which host has ip 10.20.50.121)...then you can access it on another computer by typing 10.20.50.121:81.

Now to connect your WCF service to Website,you need to check if your wcf service is running or not.For that when you publish your wcf service to IIS you get 3 files out of which one is **default.svc**(or any of your name you can click on the service go to contents view and see it) click it and on the right hand side click **browse** if you see a success page that your service is running then you need to copy that address an paste it in your Website **webconfig** endpoint address location and change the appopriate dns value .That should get your WCF service started

Comment: yes, i know what you've said. I do have installed iis and the default page is just my project. But i don't know what to do next. I mean, i don't know the connection between it and my data service...

Comment: so your Issue is to connect WCF service and website??

Comment: yes, if i can reach my website via LAN(e.g 10.20.50.121:81), then can I directly reach my data service?(10.20.50.121:81/default.svc)

Comment: Generally i've learned your idea.But i don't know how to operate it. I mean, how to publish my wcf data service to IIS?  BTW:What I mean is WCF data service instead of WCF service(I don't know the difference between them either.) Sorry to say that maybe my question is so simple but i'm a rookie..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764469/how-to-host-wcf-data-service-odata-in-iis7 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg192995.aspx

Answer (score 0):

can you access it from your own computer using 192.168.1.4:61388/default.svc ? Or only localhost ? Run netstat -a and check the webserver is actually binding to the 1.4 address and not just to your local loopback adapter (127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual directly pointing to folder where your wcf svc is lying and try accessing it.